# Angular page refresh on child route

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I have a lazy loading of modules in this manner:

```
{
path: 'main',
data: {title: ' - '},
component: LandingComponent,
resolve: { images: RouteResolverService },
children: [
  {
    path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full',
  },
  {
    path: 'home',
    loadChildren: () => import('../app/home/home.module').then(mod => mod.HomeModule),
  },
  {
    path: 'courses',
    loadChildren: () => import('../app/courses/courses.module').then(mod => mod.CoursesModule),
  },
  {
    path: 'students',
    loadChildren: () => import('../app/students/students.module').then(mod => mod.StudentsModule),
  },
  {
    path: 'forum',
    loadChildren: () => import('../app/forum/forum.module').then(mod => mod.ForumModule),
  },
  {
    path: 'contact',
    loadChildren: () => import('../app/contact/contact.module').then(mod => mod.ContactModule),
  },
  {
    path: 'profile',
    loadChildren: () => import('../app/profile/profile.module').then(mod => mod.ProfileModule),
  }
]
```

}

Now, suppose I am on route 'main/profile' and try to refresh the page, the app navigates to 'main/home'. I know why this is happening, I would like to get some help on stopping it.

What I would like to achieve is, if I am on 'main/profile', on page refresh, I should still be on 'main/profile'.

Comment: post code instead of screenshots

Comment: replaced screenshot with code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
constructor(public route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) {
    this.loading = true;
    this.param1 = this.route.snapshot.params.param1;
    this.param2 = this.route.snapshot.params.param2;
    // get data
}

navigateToChild(param3: string) {
    this.router.navigate([param3], { relativeTo: this.route });
}
```